# In Kotlin JS calling getHours on a date gives TypeError: date.getHours is not a function

Tags: kotlin-js

Hopefully this is a common issue that someone can help me with ?
I've got a data class that has a kotlin,js.Date on it. If I print out the value of it via console.log I get:

```
2019-12-29T13:30:00.000+0000
```

I'm trying to get the hours portion so I do

```
date.getHours()
```

and I'm getting "TypeError: date.getHours is not a function" as a runtime error in the browser.
I don't quite understand this; does my date object not contain a date or something ?

Comment: can you show the piece of your data class? and how you call getHours from the object of your data class?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first convert it to js Date

```
new Date('2019-12-29T13:30:00.000+0000').getHours()
```

and then you can call its functions.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was doing an unsafe cast and what I thought was a js date was actually a string :-)